# Read and Write to a XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to read a file where the file path is in a XML and then write the contents in that file to another new xml using only xslt assuming all files are in the same folder.

The requirement is, open and read the input.xml and find the file path in "filepath" tag and then open and read the AddressBook01.xml which is in "filepath" and then read "Name" tag in the AddressBook01.xml file and write them in to a file like Name01.xml.

Basically if sufficient to know how to read and write to files using XSLT.

Is this possible? I'm new to this and any help is much appreciated.

**Input XML in input.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddressFiles>
   <AddressFile>
      <name>AdressBook01</name>
      <filepath>AddressBook01.xml</filepath>
   </AddressFile>
<AddressFiles>
```

**Contents in AddressBook01.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContactDetails>
    <Contact>
       <Name>Tom</Name>
       <Address>Toms Address</Address>
    </Contact>
    <Contact>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Address>Peters Address</Address>
    </Contact>
</ContactDetails>
```

**Expected output in Names01.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Name>Tom</Name>
<Name>Peter</Name>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an XSLT 2.0 processor you can read in the file with the `doc` function and create a result document using `xsl:result-document` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="AddressFile">
  <xsl:result-document href="Names{replace(name, '[^0-9]+', '')}.xml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="doc(filepath)//Contact/Name"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that your expected output lacks a root element containing the `Name` elements so it is not a well-formed XML document. It is possible to create that result format and my suggestion does that but in most cases it is better to create well-formed XML documents as otherwise there are few ways to read/process the created file with XML tools.

Comment: What if I'm using XSLT 1.0? How can I do the same thing then?

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor do you use? Some support http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html to create a result document, reading in a document can be done with `document(filepath)//Contact/Name` instead of `doc(filepath)//Contact/Name`.